# we get string form web service that string how to convert NsString to NSDate in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, json, web-services, nsstring, nsdate

**i have tried like this**

```
 cell.msgid.text=[[tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"MobileMessageMasterId"];

NSString *datefromweb= [[tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"MessageDateTime"];

NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"];

NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateformatter dateFromString:datefromweb];

[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"MMM yyyy"];

NSString *month1 = [dateformatter stringFromDate:dateFromString];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];

NSString *time= [dateformatter stringFromDate:dateFromString];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"dd"];

NSString *day1= [dateformatter stringFromDate:dateFromString];
```

we get string in datefromweb(**NSString**) variable but not get in
datefromstring(**NSDate**) variable and i am separate out date,time,month,year.

my response is

```
 { MessageDateTime = "19/01/2016 14:16:03";}
```

Comment: `NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];` the `dateFromString = [dateformatter dateFromString:...];` That's useless alloc/init there. You need to be more specific, but showing/debugging yourself where there is nil value. My guess ? `dateFromString` is `nil`, so all the following results are messed up too. It's because of the hour format: `hh` vs `HH`. That's the first issue that is causing all the rest to not work.

Comment: explain reason why u down vote @ downvoter

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
NSString *yourString = @"";  // use your string here where you will get from JSON
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]]; // Set timezone whatever you want
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *convertedDate = [formatter dateFromString:yourString];
NSLog(@"%@",convertedDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Get Date string from web

NSString *datefromweb= @"19/01/2016 14:16:03";


//Set Date Formatter
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

//Convert string into Date
NSDate *selectedDate = [df dateFromString: datefromweb];

//For Setting new format to NSDate need to create new NSDateFormatter.

NSDateFormatter *df1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[df1 setDateFormat:@"dd"];
NSString* myDayString = [df1 stringFromDate:selectedDate];

[df1 setDateFormat:@"MMM"];
NSString* myMonthString = [df1 stringFromDate:selectedDate];

[df1 setDateFormat:@"MM"];
NSString* myMonthString1 = [df1 stringFromDate:selectedDate];

[df1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];
NSString* myYearString = [df1 stringFromDate:selectedDate];


[df1 setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
NSString* myTimeString = [df1 stringFromDate:selectedDate];
```

Output :

```
 Date 19 
 Month Name Jan - 01  
 Year 2016
 Time 02:16 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NSDateComponents is better approach

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:@"19/01/2016 14:16:03"];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comonents =
[gregorian components:(NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth |  NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond
                       ) fromDate:date];
NSInteger day = [comonents day];
NSInteger month = [comonents month];
NSInteger year = [comonents year];
NSInteger hour = [comonents hour];
NSInteger minutes = [comonents minute];
NSInteger seconds = [comonents second];
```